# How to apply ngClass to only one table head

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

**HTML**

```
<th>Car Name <i (click)="sortData('carName')" [ngClass]="custom" class="fa sort-icon"></i></th>

<th>Car Status <i (click)="sortData('carStatus')" [ngClass]="custom" class="fa sort-icon"></i></th>
```

**TS**

```
sortData(name) {
  this.pipeFlag = !this.pipeFlag;
  this.custom = (this.pipeFlag === true) ? 'fa-arrow-down' : 'fa-arrow-up';
}
```

I am trying to apply a font awesome class to table heads on click but it gets applied to both table heads. How do i apply it only to the table head that I click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding both table heads' `ngClass`es  to the same variable: `[ngClass]="custom"`, so when `custom` changes, both table heads will be updated.

You could create an object that would hold classes for different elements, like this:

```
public custom = {
  carName: 'fa-arrow-down'
  carStatus: 'fa-arrow-down'
};
```

Then your `sortData` method will look as follows:

```
sortData(name) {
  this.pipeFlag = !this.pipeFlag;
  this.custom[name] = (this.pipeFlag === true) ? 'fa-arrow-down' : 'fa-arrow-up';
}
```

And HTML:

```
<th>Car Name <i (click)="sortData('carName')" [ngClass]="custom['carName']" class="fa sort-icon"></i></th>
<th>Car Status <i (click)="sortData('carStatus')" [ngClass]="custom['carStatus']" class="fa sort-icon"></i></th>
```

Comment: thank you your solution worked and  it is applicable to my use case

Answer (score 1):

You just two `boolean` fagging whethe the class is one or the other.

```
<th>
    Car Name 
    <i (click)="sortData('carName')" class="fa sort-icon" 
     [ngClass]="{
          'fa-arrow-down': !iconClasses.carName,
          'fa-arrow-up': iconClasses.carName
     }"></i>
</th>
<!-- The other th tag analogue but pointing to iconClasses.carStatus -->
```

Let's define what `iconClasses` is.

```
interface IconClasses {
    carName: boolean;
    carStatus: boolean;
}
```

So, `iconClasses` will store the actual flag per icon.

```
// Initialize iconClasses in your Component class.
public iconClasses: IconClasses = {
    carName: false;
    carStatus: false;
}

// ...

sortData = icon => {
    const flag = this.iconClasses[icon];
    this.iconClasses[icon] = !flag;
}
```

By changing the flag, Angular keeps a tracking on the actual value so the class will be swapped under the scenes.

There is too many ways to achieve the same behavior.
Here's how I would do it.

By the way, `[ngClass]` has lots of overwrites, one of them is the one I used which expects an object where every key is the class name and the value is a `boolean` indication where or not is applied.
Here's some [extra information](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) from the documentation.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using same property for both th you can do below 2 things

1) apply `ngClass` to only Car Name `th` if you want class to apply in first `th` only

or

2) Simply Call function in ngClass and pass a flag like

```
(click)="sortData('name')" // for name
(click)="sortData('status')" // for status
```

and in function do something like this.

```
sortData(type) {
  this.pipeFlag = !this.pipeFlag;
  if(type === 'name'){
   this.custom =  (this.pipeFlag === true) ? 'fa-arrow-down' : 'fa-arrow-up';
  } else if(type === 'status'){
    // status related stuff
  } 
}
```